# Mutate in two elements group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe and I'd like to generate the column `b` with a `mutate`. The column `b` is the other `a` element of the group.

```
tibble::tribble(
  ~group,  ~a,  ~b,
     "A", 23L, 32L,
     "A", 32L, 23L,
     "B", 65L, 98L,
     "B", 98L, 65L,
     "C", 76L, 44L,
     "C", 44L, 76L
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing that there are always only two elements per group, you can `rev`erse the `unique` values of `a` per group (I created a new variable `c` here so you can verify that it equals `b`):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~group,  ~a,  ~b,
  "A", 23L, 32L,
  "A", 32L, 23L,
  "B", 65L, 98L,
  "B", 98L, 65L,
  "C", 76L, 44L,
  "C", 44L, 76L
)

df %>% 
  dplyr::group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(c = rev(unique(a)))

#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   group     a     b     c
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 A        23    32    32
#> 2 A        32    23    23
#> 3 B        65    98    98
#> 4 B        98    65    65
#> 5 C        76    44    44
#> 6 C        44    76    76
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use

```
 df1b <- with(df1, ave(a, group, FUN = rev))
```